# Formik resetForm not triggering field onChange

Tags: reactjs, formik

Apparently when you reset a form, it doesn't automatically trigger field onChange.

See this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-sgdfn
(Type in a valid email address then click Reset, as opposed to emptying the field using keyboard Backspace)

[image]

```
<input id="email"
       value={values.email}
       onChange={customHandleChange} // This is not triggered on reset
       />
```

Is there any way to make resetForm call all field onChange?

Comment: seems to be working.

Comment: @JuniusL. Are you saying the onChange handler is triggered when you click the Reset button?

Comment: As you mentioned in question, I typed a valid email ID and then clicked on 'Reset' button. And it cleared the the email id. Isn't it the expected? If not, please elaborate more. @Aximili

Comment: Sorry guys I thought the title and comment in the sample code were clear enough. I have added a screenshot to show the effect of `customHandleChange` not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no way. See https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1584

You'll need a custom reset handler that resets the form and do additional things like resetting states.